# Создание подчиненной формы с не явной ссылкой на таблицу

Tags: sql, база-данных, access

Имеется таблица с компаниями `common` и необходимо создать таблицу, которая показывает, что одна одна компания из таблице `common` может поставлять несколько типов товара в другую компанию из той же таблицы. Реализовал это создав индексированную таблицу `supplier_recipient`, в которой 3 атрибута с типом продукта, продавцов, получателем. (`key_product_type`, `key_supplier`, `key_supplier`). Создал подчиненную форму для реализации связи многие ко многим.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вроде бы все хорошо, но в полях со списком нам необходимо ссылаться на таблицу `general_data`, которая не явно определена в таблице `supplier_recipient`, а через таблицу `common`:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в результате чего возникает ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос: Как создать рабочие поля со списком при не явной связи?

База данных находится [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/tmC7qzkkqcuYA).